# Copy and paste selected text from vim file

Tags: linux, vim, copy

I use the following command to copy the content of a text file (located in remote server) opened with VIM (Linux OS):

```
gg v shift+g
```

The text is selected and greyd out as seen in the screenshot[image]

But I don't know how to copy it in clipboard in order to paste it later in another vim file (in my host machine)

Comment: Check this: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard

Comment: also the visual mode is not needed here: `ggYG` directly makes a copy

Comment: this is not a dup! OP's problem is copy stuff to the clipboard (or to local vim) from a **remote** machine.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you are going in the wrong way.

I guess you opened the remote file via ssh. You cannot copy to your local clipboard directly over a remote ssh.

I would suggest that, you open the file from your local vim, via `:e scp://server//path/file` or open it in a split window in your local vim. Then you are free to yank/copy content from your remote file to your local vim file(s).